# Dynamically change uri() method's value in spring-cloud-gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

Is it possible to somehow dynamically change the value of the `uri()` method in `spring-cloud-gateway`?

I have this method:

```
    private <T extends RequestData> Function<PredicateSpec, Route.AsyncBuilder> walletRoute(String server, String path, String method, Class<T> inClass) {
    return r -> r.path(path)
                 .and().method(method)
                 .and().readBody(inClass, requestBody ->
                    findWalletInstanceWithUserRef(requestBody.getPlayerExternalReference()).equals(server))
                 .uri("http://" + server).id("th");
}
```

This method call returns the hostname I want to put inside `uri()`:

```
findWalletInstanceWithUserRef(requestBody.getPlayerExternalReference())
```

Is it somehow possible to do that?

Thank you

Comment: not without writing another filter. The body is cached and a filter later can update the request attribute that has the target uri.

Comment: @spencergibb, thank you. Could you please provide an example with code? It would be really helpful.

Comment: @spencergibb even if you write a filter to mutate the request, uri is used anyway. I think that for Spring Gateway it's IMPOSSIBLE to do this simple thing.

Comment: It's not impossible. We do it in gateway. It's a matter of ordering.